# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory

Tags: java, rest, maven, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am trying to deploy a maven web application on my local wildfly machine. But I am getting this error:

```
08:55:02,595 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-55) UT005023: Exception handling request to /reg-server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/v1/lineage: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.Unhandled
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that at deploy time, the application is looking for a directory which has not been generated at package time thus the problem. When created in the target/lib then the deployment runs ok.

Answer (score 24):

./gradlew assembleDebug --rerun-tasks

This command run in the command prompt will work if you are trying to connect multiple code bases using settings.gradle and get this error.

Comment: I prefer this answer as you can specify the modules failing on the CLI to build without having to invalidate your entire cache and restarting the IDE

Comment: This is certainly the better anwer.

Comment: sometimes this execution in terminal may failed  because of other reasons. But the directory issue will sow

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

1. Go to `Build.gradle(Module: app)` and enable make `databinding => enable :false`.
2. Rebuild your project.

Comment: deletin .gradle folder and invalidating solved it as no one can disable databinding

Comment: Even just deleting ".gradle" folder was enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had encountered the similar error in Android Studio. I just invalidated the cache and restarted the IDE. I suppose it has some thing to do with stale cache data which do not get updated during build processes. Thus, when you undo some changes which previously resulted in creation and deletion of packages and classes, like DataBinding classes in Android Studio. You are left with directories which do not exist and IDE never updated the caches to reflect the same in following builds. Thus, even if after cleaning and rebuilding, error persist. Hope this helps.

In Android Studio, goto FILE -> Invalidate Cache and Restart.

Comment: This didn't work for me. However, invoking Gradle from the command line with the `--rerun-tasks` flag _did_. I was also experiencing a databinding issue.

Comment: This didn't work for me as well, i am using data binding

Comment: I had to delete the .gradle folder before invalidating as suggested in [this answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55116942/2811075)

Comment: removing .gradle, invalidating the cache and restarting worked for me

Comment: remove .gradle fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

For me it solved by deleting the .gradle folder and running the build again.

Answer (score 1):

in build.gradle
I changed buildFeatures.dataBinding = true to buildFeatures.dataBinding = false
and it's worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For me, deleting the .gradle directory did nothing.  I was running my instrumentation tests on an emulator, and I had to wipe the data on it then do a cold boot.  Voila!  The tests ran.