# Android databinding errors while building

Tags: android, android-databinding

I can't build project because of this error. I removed databinding implementation from one fragment and now project doesn't build. I checked carefully layout if I haven't left anything up there.

It throws error on Run tasks->:app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesMockDebug->Execute writeBaseClasses

I tried so far clean, build project, restart and invalidate caches, reimport project anyway shows same error without any clues whats wrong

> Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
>
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesMockDebug'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipCachedTaskExecuter.execute(SkipCachedTaskExecuter.java:103)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
>       at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.validateListFilesParameters(FileUtils.java:545)
>       at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:521)
>       at android.databinding.tool.store.ResourceBundle.loadClassInfoFromFolder(ResourceBundle.java:157)
>       at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput$deps$2.invoke(LayoutInfoInput.kt:63)
>       at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput$deps$2.invoke(LayoutInfoInput.kt:30)
>       at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:154)
>       at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput.getDeps(LayoutInfoInput.kt)
>       at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput$existingBindingClasses$2.invoke(LayoutInfoInput.kt:86)
>       at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput$existingBindingClasses$2.invoke(LayoutInfoInput.kt:30)
>       at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:154)
>       at android.databinding.tool.store.LayoutInfoInput.getExistingBindingClasses(LayoutInfoInput.kt)
>       at android.databinding.tool.BaseDataBinder.(BaseDataBinder.kt:40)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask$CodeGenerator.run(DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.kt:203)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.writeBaseClasses(DataBindingGenBaseClassesTask.kt:100)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>       ... 35 more

Answer (score 40):

Delete the `.gradle` directory then invalidate and restart Android Studio.

Comment: .gradle folder of your **project,** not `c:\users\xxx\xxx`

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this while moving a bunch of stuff around in one of my projects. Nothing worked: invalidate/restart, nuking all gradle caches, clearing AS cache/settings, etc.

Then one of my colleagues suggested: `git clean -fdx` followed by a restart of Android Studio and it did the trick. It nukes anything in your tree that didn't come directly from your repo originally.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it does not make sense. 
When I removed the project from android studio and re-imported it, the problem is fixed. However i deleted build folder or tried restart and invalidate caches it did not fixed. I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix-like system (Linux or BSD) do the following:

1. Exit Android Studio (or at least close the project)
2. Open up a terminal
3. Enter the following command:

`rm -rf .gradle .idea $( find . -name build -type d ) $( find . -name *.iml -type f )`

4. Import the project again from Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I just delete the .gradle folder and restarted android studio and it works