# Parameter 'directory' is not a directory error coming in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, build, parameters, directory

This error coming when I am building a Android project in Android Studio.Please tell me How to solve?

```
Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018148/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-directory-is-not-a-directory-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if the path you have assigned for the resource is correct ?

Comment: I have already checked.But this problem is coming when I reinstall android studio because I had a bug issue. You can find the same problem here but I can not file how to solve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018148/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-directory-is-not-a-directory-in/55234412?noredirect=1#comment97202317_55234412.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced a similar issue and tried the following answer. it was useful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61069705/12315038

git clean -fdx followed by a restart of Android Studio and it did the trick. It nukes anything in your tree that didn't come directly from your repo originally.